# How to pass Byte Array as a class property to OData function in ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am using **OData V4** with ASP.NET Web API. After doing a lot of research and experiments I am still not able to pass the Byte array (`byte[]`) as a class model property. I am not sure that how the .Net Framework is receiving it as a string. But when I configure the controller action to receive only the Byte array (`byte[]`) parameter then it receives the correct data. It does not receive it as a class property.

Here is my class model.

```
public class TempFileModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the OData model configuration:

```
public class TransientFileConfiguration : IModelConfiguration
{
    public void Apply(ODataModelBuilder builder, ApiVersion apiVersion, string routePrefix)
    {
        builder.EntitySet<TransientFileModel>("TransientFiles");
        builder.EntityType<TransientFileModel>().HasKey(e => e.Key);

        builder.Action("UploadFile")
            .Returns<List<string>>()
            .CollectionParameter<TempFileModel>("file");
    }
}
```

My Controller action for this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ODataRoute("UploadFile")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> UploadFile(ODataActionParameters parameters)
{
    var paramValue = parameters["file"];

    return Ok(new List<string>());
}
```

The error I get every time:
Error Message: "**Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Byte[]'.**"

[image]

Here are few links that I have searched for unbound action using OData API and working with this issue:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/odata-actions-and-functions

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/action-parameter-support

[How to pass Array to OData function in ASP.NET Web API implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26634730/how-to-pass-array-to-odata-function-in-asp-net-web-api-implementation)

[How to make an unbound POST action in webapi 2.2 odata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687462/how-to-make-an-unbound-post-action-in-webapi-2-2-odata)

A question on StackOverflow with similar context maybe (just to understand the issue):

[Pass two byte array to asp.net web api post method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47802866/pass-two-byte-array-to-asp-net-web-api-post-method)